# Menu Tool strip Hover enable?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, toolstrip

I have used menu tool strip in my form! I want menu to be dropped down when my cursor hovers on it! How to do this?

Comment: Why would you want this? It violates all of the standard platform UI conventions. No other Windows application works this way. Why should yours be different? That will just confuse your users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the `MouseHover` event of the menu item:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  fileToolStripMenuItem.MouseHover += fileToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover;
}

private void fileToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  fileToolStripMenuItem.ShowDropDown();
}
```

or the lambda version:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  fileToolStripMenuItem.MouseHover += (s, e) => fileToolStripMenuItem.ShowDropDown();
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much I almost lost hope!

Comment: Upvoting this under duress. It's the correct solution to the wrong problem.